# how to get the values in DatePicker in java Android

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I want the user to be able to select the date of birth using the custom DatePicker from XML, the issue is that I don't know how to get the values selected and store it as a LocalDate variable because the backend stored it as a LocalDate. Firstly I customized it with DatePickerDialog but the thing is so frustrating, just imagine a user that was born in 1990, the person needs to scroll for a while before reaching that and I don't want to use that again as I came across the custom DatePicker which makes me to select the year, month and day differently. Hope you guys understands what I want to achieved. Here is the DatePicker I used in the XML to get the calendar. I want to get all the values selected and store it as a variable of type LocalDate so that I can use it in the user's registration because date of birth is one of the parameters required.

```
    <DatePicker
                                android:id="@+id/datePicker"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:calendarViewShown="false"
                                android:datePickerMode="spinner"
                                android:spinnersShown="true"/>


This is the one I used before but I don't want to use it again. It's frustrating to scroll down for a longer time if the person that want to register is a bit advanced in age.
```

this was the XML for it

<TextView

```
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="DATE OF BIRTH"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_40" />



                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_date_of_birth"
                        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:text="select here"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_40" />
```

And this was the method in the Java class

private Button btnDateOfBirth;

```
    btnDateOfBirth = findViewById(R.id.btn_date_of_birth);



private void setDatePicker(final Button btnDateOfBirth){
        Calendar current_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog dialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance((view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,monthOfYear);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DATE,dayOfMonth);
            long date_millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
            btnDateOfBirth.setText(getFormattedDateEvent(date_millis));

        },
                current_calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                current_calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                current_calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
        dialog.setThemeDark(false);
        dialog.setAccentColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cyan_800_overlay));
        //dialog.setMinDate(current_calendar);
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"Date PickerDialog");
    }
    public static String getFormattedDateEvent(Long dateTime){
        SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, yyyy MMM dd");
        return newFormat.format(new Date(dateTime));
    }
Then used a button to get and store the date selected by setting onclick to it and called the method inside the onclick

btnDateOfBirth.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            setDatePicker((Button)view);
        });
```

Comment: Not answering your question. Since you want a `LocalDate` in the end, don’t go the detour over `Calendar`. Just use `selectedDateOfBirth = LocalDate.of(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);` (need to add 1 to the month value because the date picker insanely counts months from 0 = January).

Comment: I understand what you meant but my problem is how to select the date of birth from the DatePicker. There's no option to set it when the dialog pop-ups and it's making me unable to get the actual date of Birth selected. Even to store it as a string will still be ok as I can change the data type from the backend